# How to make the nextline when writing on a file with FileWriter?

Tags: java, file, serialization

Does anyone know how to make a nextline? Usually I use the "\n" characters but when I open the .txt I wrote, I see it didn't went to the nextline.
Here's the code:

```
FileWriter f=new FileWriter(path);
f.write("bla bla \n");
f.write("bla bla");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap a BufferedWriter around it, which you should be doing anyway, and use BufferedWriter.newLine().

Or use a PrintWriter, but beware that it swallows exceptions.

If that doesn't solve your problem, use \r\n instead of just \n.

Comment: You can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the system's newline character, so your code would work on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
BufferedWriter f = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
f.write("bla bla ");
f.newLine();
f.write("bla bla");
```